# Equal Transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I want to have a transition that extends a div both at the top and bottom on hover. Right now it overlaps the div above and pushes away the div on the bottom.

I want to either push away on both sides or overlap on both sides. Not one of both.

```css
#blue, #red {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  transition: 0.8s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#blue:hover, #red:hover {
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

This is what I'm working [with](https://jsfiddle.net/cr74jzLn/):

```css
#blue, #red {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  transition: 0.8s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#blue:hover, #red:hover {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are your problems:

1. Let's remove the `float` here, this is not required.
2. Remove the negative margin, as this is what the *overlapping* code.
3. Finally, correct the HTML without the repeating ID.

Snippet here:

```css
.blue, .red {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transition: 0.8s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue:hover, .red:hover {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

PLease check this

```css
#blue, #red {
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    float: left;
    transition: 0.8s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
#blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
#red {
    background-color: red;
}
#blue:hover, #red:hover {
    height:100px;
    padding-top:25px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="blue"></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
```

Comment: What to check? **1.** Your HTML is wrong. **2.** You haven't said what you have changed. Can't find the change.

Comment: adding this padding-top:25px will work as expected!! #blue:hover, #red:hover {
    height:100px;
    padding-top:25px;
}

Comment: and mine HTML is not wrong its what has been asked in the question!

Comment: Lalit, I respect your answer. I am not saying yours is wrong. Yes, the OP's wrong. Shouldn't we maintain the quality of answers? So you are ignoring the wrong stuff, right?

Comment: thanks for the concern, i also appreciate it alot, take this use case into mind, you getting this html from the backend or somewhere and you just need to make it correct with using css. Really appreciate your eye on details

Comment: Thanks Lalit. I didn't mean to offend you. Thanks for taking it positively.

Comment: :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you guys really get what I'm trying to do. I'm not just trying to remove the overlapping, I'm trying to make the div expand on both top and bottom without interacting differently on top then on the bottom.

So for an example, if I hover over the red div, it pushes both blue divs touching it away OR overlapping both. I'm fine with either. Right now it overlaps on one end and pushes away on the other.

So to be clear, I DON'T want to simply make the div bigger without overlapping.

Thanks for the answers so far though!